# var notification = new Notification

Tags: javascript, html, sql, database

So I am trying to figure out this piece of JavaScript. The thing that I am trying to do is using a query to display the amount of notifications that are in my database. So lets say there a 5 notifications in my database is it possible to add a query to this code so it would show something like : hello u have 5 unseen messages? i have bin searching for a few hours now and its just driving me insane.

Thanks in advance

```
<html>
<head>
   <script language="javascript">
       function notifyMe() {
      // Let's check if the browser supports notifications
      if (!("Notification" in window)) {
      alert("This browser does not support desktop notification");
      }

     // Let's check if the user is okay to get some notification
     else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
     // If it's okay let's create a notification
     var notification = new Notification("Hi there!");
     }

     // Otherwise, we need to ask the user for permission
     else if (Notification.permission !== 'denied') {
     Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {
     // If the user is okay, let's create a notification
     if (permission === "granted") {
     var notification = new Notification("Hi there!");
     }
     });
     }

     // At last, if the user already denied any notification, and you 
     // want to be respectful there is no need to bother them any more.
     }
       </script>
     <title>TODO supply a title</title>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     </head>
     <body>
     <div><button onclick="notifyMe()">Meldingen ophalen</button></div>
     </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: The simplest way to accomplish this would be to do an xmlhttprequest ... say every minute or so? To check if there are any updates available.

Answer (score 1):

To get an access to your database, you'll need PHP.

If you want to execute PHP on a web page without reloading it, you have to use "xmlhttprequest" as @Grimbode said.

It's a way to get a PHP response (with, in your case, an access to your database) from a PHP function via Javascript.

To make things easier, you should take a look to the [$.post method from jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/).

Good luck with your research !

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script that will call itself every minute to check if there were an new notifications.

Your response text is totally up to you. You could send back a number, you could send back a json with all the information, etc etc.

```
setInterval(function () {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            new Notification("You have " + xmlhttp.responseText + " notifications!");
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "php_ajax_handler_url_here", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}, 60000);
```

This requires you to have php. Everytime the ajax request gets called your php file that handles that request has to access the db and send back the correct response.